# search elements in array using regex, kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I am searching for records which contain an array field `payload.params`

I would like to display all the fields which contain the string `aabb`

example: `payload.params = [3raabb, 44aabb66, grgeg]` 
display:  `3raabb, 44aabb66`

how do I use regex on arrays?

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "payload.params": "aabb"
    }
  }
}
```

get no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Elasticsearch regex documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators):

> Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match the entire string.

Thus, use

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "payload.params": ".*aabb.*"
    }
  }
}
```